# Predicting continuous variables using image and text input to neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing

I am looking to create a neural network architecture that takes two kinds of inputs: image and text, and outputs a predicted continuous variable. More specifically, I will have multiple images of a house as an input alongside numerical/text data like square meters, number of beds, baths, carspaces, latitude, longitude, features etc. I want to use this to output the predicted price value of the given house.

I understand you can combine image and text inputs as seen here:

[image]

Could I use a similar model for the situation I described? If so, what kind of neural network architecture should I use for the image and numeric/text input streams, and how would I combine them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a reasonable architecture.  You could use any architecture for processing images, and have it output a representation of the image (take any classification architecture, and remove the last layer).  You could also use any architecture for text, and have it output a representation of the text.  Finally, for other inputs, you could use a fully connected architecture.  Then, concatenate those representations and run them through another fully connected network.  That would be a reasonable architecture to try.